# How to install wget on LFS system

Tags: linux, operating-system, wget, linux-from-scratch

I am pretty newbie to Linux and started LFS because I needed it for school. So my system is now perfectly running with an internet connection, but I still don't have any packet manager or something. The first binary I would like to have is basically wget, but I really don't know how to do...

Could someone explain to me please ?

Comment: [Beyond Linux From Scratch: wget](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/wget.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has a list of other SE sites that you can look thru to find one appropriate for this questions.

Answer (score 1):

I personally used (and would highly recommend) using the existing Linux system (the host) to download the wget package and its dependencies before booting your LFS system for the first time. However, seeing that you're already using your LFS system, if you still have the ability to log using the host, then use it to download wget as if it was one of the sources that you got when building the LFS system.

For me, I used a Linux Mint Host running in VirtualBox to build my LFS. To get wget I just had to re-add the Linux Mint host storage, and download wget and added it to the LFS sources. I then removed the Linux Mint host storage, logged in to my LFS machine, then followed the steps in [BLFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/wget.html).

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is mainly just from parts of lfs and the wget page of blfs.
1. Boot into your host OS.
2. Enter the following commands in the command line to get into chroot(edit depending on your partitions and where you mount lfs):

```
sudo su -

export LFS=/mnt/lfs
mount -vt ext4 /dev/sda4 $LFS
mount -v --bind /dev $LFS/dev
mount -vt devpts devpts $LFS/dev/pts -o gid=5,mode=620
mount -vt proc proc $LFS/proc
mount -vt sysfs sysfs $LFS/sys
mount -vt tmpfs tmpfs $LFS/run
if [ -h $LFS/dev/shm ]; then
  mkdir -pv $LFS/$(readlink $LFS/dev/shm)
fi
chroot "$LFS" /usr/bin/env -i              \
    HOME=/root TERM="$TERM" PS1='\u:\w\$ ' \
    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin     \
    /bin/bash --login
```

3. Download wget from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.19.1.tar.xz and copy it into /mnt/lfs/sources from your host os.
4. Unpack and cd into it with:

```
tar -xf wget-1.19.1.tar.xz
cd wget-1.19.1
```

5. Configure and install wget with:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr      \
            --sysconfdir=/etc  \
            --with-ssl=openssl &&
make
make install
```

6. Delete the wget-1.19.1 folder if you want and your done!